# `fasterRCNNLayers` for simple custom network give error message

Tags: matlab, faster-rcnn

When using `fasterRCNNLayers` for creating faster rcnn network from custom network, it gives error message for upgrading the network to faster rcnn network. `matlab 2022a update 3` is used.

I have traced the error and found the problem is caused by deleting classification layers and adding faster-rcnn layers. What's the restrictions for upgrading network and I can't found related clue from the documents.

My cnn network code is as follows: `cup_use_net_h.m`

```
numTrainingFiles = 30;
[imdsTrain,imdsTest] = splitEachLabel(imds,numTrainingFiles,'randomize');


layers = [ ...
    imageInputLayer([180 60 1])
    convolution2dLayer(5,40)
    reluLayer
    maxPooling2dLayer(2,'Stride',2)
    convolution2dLayer(5,10)
    reluLayer
    maxPooling2dLayer(5,'Stride',5)
    fullyConnectedLayer(2,'Name','fc') %% fullyConnectedLayer(10)
    softmaxLayer
    classificationLayer];

options = trainingOptions('sgdm', ...
    'MaxEpochs',100,...
    'InitialLearnRate',1e-2, ...
     'Verbose',true, ...
    'Plots','training-progress');


net = trainNetwork(imdsTrain,layers,options);
save("cup_single_mark_net.mat","net");
```

My `fasterRCNNLayers` calling program is as follows: `cup_faster_rcnn_c.m`

```
% load("cup_single_mark_net.mat");
% trainingDataTable = objectDetectorTrainingData(gTruth);


load("cup_single_mark_net.mat");
singlenet = net;
inputImageSize = [450,400,1];
featureLayer = 'relu_2';
anchorBoxes = [180,60; 150,50];
numClasses = 2;
lgraph = fasterRCNNLayers(inputImageSize,numClasses,anchorBoxes, ...
                          singlenet,featureLayer)
analyzeNetwork(lgraph);
```

error message is as follows:

```
>> cup_faster_rcnn_c
Error using nnet.cnn.LayerGraph>iValidateLayerName
Layer 'fc' does not exist.

Error in nnet.cnn.LayerGraph>iGetDestinationInformation (line 625)
iValidateLayerName( endLayerName, layerNames );

Error in nnet.cnn.LayerGraph/disconnectLayers (line 372)
                iGetDestinationInformation(d, this.PrivateDirectedGraph.Nodes.Layers);

Error in vision.internal.cnn.RCNNLayers/insertOrReplaceROIPooling (line 717)
                lgraph = lgraph.disconnectLayers(featureExtractionLayer, outLayers{ii});

Error in vision.internal.cnn.RCNNLayers/fastRCNNForNonSequentialNetworks (line 646)
                [lgraph, numFiltersLastConvLayer] = insertOrReplaceROIPooling(this, lgraph, featureExtractionLayer);

Error in vision.internal.cnn.RCNNLayers.createFasterRCNN (line 165)
                lgraph = fastRCNNForNonSequentialNetworks(obj, numClasses, lgraph, 'faster-rcnn', anchorBoxes, featureExtractionLayer);

Error in fasterRCNNLayers (line 174)
    lgraph = vision.internal.cnn.RCNNLayers.createFasterRCNN(...

Error in cup_faster_rcnn_c (line 12)
lgraph = fasterRCNNLayers(inputImageSize,numClasses,anchorBoxes, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `feature_layers` parameter should be `conv_2` not `relu_2`.